# MVC3/Razor Error: The view or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Area called Admin.  The folder structure in Visual Studio is this:

```
Areas
   Admin
      Controllers
      Views
```

I have a controller called AccountController in which I have a Action called Verify.  I have this line of code in this action:

```
return View("EmailVerificationComplete");
```

But, I get this error:

The view 'EmailVerificationComplete' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/Account/EmailVerificationComplete.aspx
~/Views/Account/EmailVerificationComplete.ascx
~/Views/Shared/EmailVerificationComplete.aspx
~/Views/Shared/EmailVerificationComplete.ascx
~/Views/Account/EmailVerificationComplete.cshtml
~/Views/Account/EmailVerificationComplete.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/EmailVerificationComplete.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/EmailVerificationComplete.vbhtml

Why is this?  Why does MVC not know to look in the Views folder relative to the Admin area?

How do I solve this?

Thanks,

Sachin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Why does MVC not know to look in the Views folder relative to the Admin area?

Because your `AccountController` is not inside the `Admin` area. It's probably in `~/Controllers/AdminController.cs` so by convention ASP.NET MVC will look in `~/Views/Shared` or `~/Views/Account` for its corresponding views.

Comment: This is not it.  The AccountController is inside the Admin area.

Comment: @Sachin, and how did you request this controller action? Was it `/Admin/Account/Verify` or was it just `/Account/Verify`? If you requested it without the `Area` prefix in your url, then it's as if the AccountController was in your root.

Comment: Hmm, that's weird. Let me see if I can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Unable to reproduce. Steps: 1. create a new ASP.NET MVC 3 application. 2. Delete the `~/Controllers/AccountController.cs` file. 3. Right click on the project and select add new area called Admin. 4. Add `~/Areas/Admin/Controllers/AccountController.cs` with the following action: `public ActionResult Verify() { return View("EmailVerificationComplete"); }`. 5. Add a corresponding `~/Areas/Admin/Views/Account/EmailVerificationComplete.cshtml` view. 6. Run the application and navigate to `/admin/account/verify`. 7. As expected the AccountController in the admin area is executed and view rendered.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem.
What I found was when you send a request for certain action, even if the url is invalid, mvc tries to match the action for you based on the url passed in. if a match is found, (in my case it goes to the correct controller action method),  is executed, but because the path you passed in was wrong, it was not able to find the view associated.

Comment: Yeah this one just wasted my last 2 hours.  The controller action in my area was found and i could step and and debug the controller just fine, when it came to render the view however it didn't try to resolve it in the area and kept looking at the top level.  For me this was not intuitive that a controller can be resolved without the area referenced, but the view cannot

Answer (score 3):

For me, I was trying to pass in a simple string to the view.  This was causing the View() to render the wrong overload which was View(string viewName), but what I really wanted was View(object model).  So the solution was simply to cast the string to an object.  Or I could have used the ViewBag and not pass anything to the View().

Answer (score 1):

I've run into this error before...  In my case, it happened that the .csproj file was inadvertantly left out of the merge to the RELEASE branch and therefore didn't have the file that was missing indexed into the project. Once the .csproj was merged, rebuilt and deployed the file was able to be found.

Answer (score 1):

use 
return View(model:"EmailVerificationComplete");

Comment: Why don't you elaborate?